# Excel does't save query cell reference parameters

Tags: sql, excel

In a Excel workbook I'm using a cells value as a parameter when getting data from an external data sorurce through "WHERE somedata=?". I then assign "Parameter 1" to a cell reference.

This works great but when I save the workbook and then open it up again the reference to the cell is deleted. This makes Excel top crash when I try to open the workbook again.

Is this a BUG?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you clarify the problem and how SQL is related to Excel here?

Comment: Excel is making a SQL query to an external datasource. To be able to switch between departments we can change department number on one sheet and then data for that department is loaded from database. We can't load all data so we're limiting the data range by using the department value in the query as a parameter. The problem is that this reference is not saved when I save the workbook. When I open up the workbook again the reference is empty and this causes Excel to crash if I don't open in protected mode.

Comment: I upvoted you to counter the downvote though I don't know how to fix your problem.

Comment: I found this posting related to this. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom/query-parameters-cell-reference-not-saved/85a83bbc-545c-4572-b39b-f296b3415efb It's strange that this has been an issue since Office2007 and still no solution.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Excel.  It also has some bugs in handling of dates.  It could be that fixing the bug would break backwards compatibility.  Hence, the bug is baked into the cake.